# How to display Month in TEXT format using SQL query in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, format, text

I create one Data Extension name is 'TEST' using Day, Month and Year fields. I have done this scenario in number format. But I need to Display Month in Text format. How is it possible? please anybody help on this

Comment: What about using SSJS if you need to automate it? Because you cannot use if-else statements to write the name of the month instead of number via SQL. You can also use AMPscript but cannot automate it as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to display the full name of the month via the SQL query you have written, I would use the below code - utilizing the [FORMAT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/) function inside of SQL:

`FORMAT(yourDateField, 'MMMM')`

This will format the date to only display the full named Month.

Input: `01/24/2019 12:00AM`
Output: `January`

Another option if you want the abbreviation is to use `MMM` like so:

`FORMAT(yourDateField, 'MMM')`

Input: `01/24/2019 12:00AM`
Output: `Jan`

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) is a pretty comprehensive list of custom formats for SQL Dates.

---

If you are populating this DE outside of SQL, I would do the following Query: (assuming that 'pKey' is the primary Key for your DE - replace with your actual primary key(s))

```
SELECT pKey,
FORMAT(yourDateField, 'MMMM')
FROM [yourDE]

/* Target: yourDE */
/* Action: Update */
```

This will take the month numbers in your current DE and then convert them to the full string names inside your existing DE.  This will require the 'Update' action as your source and target DE are the same.